# AADB2C90304: User journey went into a bad state. Claims exchange with id 'LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange' could not be found in orchestration step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy based on [SocialAndLocal](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml) sample.

It adds 2 ClaimsTransformation steps in front.
This are steps 3 and 4:

```
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections> 
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="Social1Exchange" /> 
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="Social2Exchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AdTesttenantExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Social1Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Social1Exchange-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Social2Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Social2Exchange-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AdTesttenantExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AdTesttenantExchange-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" /> 
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Fresh logon scenario works fine. But on subsequent logons, if the user used one of the social IDPs they get an error like this:
[image]

It makes no sense. Why is B2C looking for LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange in step 4 when it's defined in step 3?

I tried asking MSFT support but so far they were no help (as usual). Maybe I can have more luck here..

I can provide an Application Insights trace if it's useful.

Comment: Can you share more of the UserJourney please? At least step 4?

Comment: @JustinWilloughby done, though I'd say it's fairly standard

Comment: Thanks. What are the two claims transformations you added in steps 1 and 2? Additionally, what session management tech profiles are being used for your various claims providers?

Comment: @JustinWilloughby I'm happy to provide all the details, but maybe it would be better to move to chat?

Comment: OK @JustinWilloughby how about we try the chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246102/aadb2c90304-user-journey-went-into-a-bad-state-claims-exchange-with-id-localac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After over 4 months MSFT support finally came up with a solution.

The error goes away if `ValidationClaimsExchangeId` element is placed as last element like this:

```
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections> 
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="Social1Exchange" /> 
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="Social2Exchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AdTesttenantExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
```

Comment: Any updates from MSFT?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jakub. We're currently experiencing similar behavior while users perform social signup. However, as we are using MSAL to trigger the flows, it seems that it's somehow restarting the same journey after it successfully finishes. That looks like a tricky one.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using more than one instance of MSAL due to micro frontend design, which is a known issue, but we've no idea on how to validate it properly.

Comment: Not sure about multiple instances, but social signup and reusing existing session fit my description.
Had a call today about it with MSFT maybe they will finally come up with something

Comment: Look forward to updates, Jakub. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't mind, how did you manage to get a call with MS folks?

Comment: Get hold of your "Customer Success Manager" and complain to them

Answer (score 3):

I had almost similar issue when I implemented Forgot password,

```
AADB2C90304: User journey went into a bad state. Claims exchange with id 'SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange' could not be found in orchestration step '2'.
```

the issue might be mostly with UserJourney. In ,
In my case, changing the value of ClaimsExchange Id to "SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" fixed the issue.

```
<ClaimsExchanges>
<ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange"
```

If you have named anything else. Try changing the Claim ID with the one mentioned in error message.

Ideally, only TechnicalProfileReferenceId carries significance but with this specific error even the ClaimsExchangeID seems important in such scenarios.

Comment: Ran into the same thing implementing "forgot password". This should be stated in the instructions, or at the very least stated in one of the "Tips".