# Azure B2C how to fix error when forcing password reset error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing force password reset policy from the samples to the customized policy. I am getting this error and I couldn't find any solution. I tried to debug from start to end and the error seems to be as soon as I add the line highlighted in the screenshot.
The sample I am following is from this link: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset.xml

Has anyone seen this error before?

[image]
Line in the code:

[image]

Comment: Came across this post and check if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832474/aadb2c90304-user-journey-went-into-a-bad-state-claims-exchange-with-id-locala,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I implemented Forgot password, the issue might be mostly with UserJourney. In `<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">`,
try changing the value of ClaimsExchange Id to "Not specified", if you have named anything else, this might seem very funny but it worked in my case.

Ideally, only TechnicalProfileReferenceId carries significance but with this specific error even the ClaimsExchangeID seems important in such scenarios.